# bash: Correctly expanding parameters from variable for dialog

Tags: bash, dialog, eval

I've been struggling with expanding flags from a variable for the bash command `dialog`.

I have the following input (reduced):

```
~/ $ pacmd list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
         ...
            alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
            ...
    index: 1
         ...
            alsa.name = "ALC3232 Analog"
            ...
```

I'm piping it through the following:

```
grep "alsa.name\|index" | sed "s/^[ \*\t]*//g" | sed "s/ =/:/g" | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}' | paste -s -d ' '
```

This gets me something like:

```
0 "HDMI 0" 2 "ALC3232 Analog"
```

Now, I want to use these as menu items for `dialog`. Ultimately, I want something like:

```
dialog --title "Interface" --menu "Please choose an option:" $args 3 "Exit"
```

becomes

```
dialog --title "Interface" --menu "Please choose an option:" 0 "HDMI 0" 2 "ALC3232 Analog" 3 "Exit"
```

But, when I do something like

```
eval "dialog --title \"Interface\" --menu \"Please choose an option:\" $args 3 \"Exit\""
```

I get

```
Error: Expected 2 arguments, found only 1.
Use --help to list options.
```

I've tried many, many approaches, all all seem to fail. I've tried the `eval` approach and I've tried putting `0 "HDMI 0" 2 "ALC3232 Analog"` into an array, but I'm running low on ideas.

If I run the desired output, it works great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is  the desired output you run that works great? The part after "becomes" does not work for me.

Comment: @thatotherguy That part was to clarify what I wanted the behavior to be like

Comment: The code you say you wanted it to be like gives you the exact same error say you didn't want. Copy-paste failure, maybe. In any case, I'm glad you figured it out :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem!

It turns out that I omitted a few arguments to `dialog` itself. The command should have been

```
eval "dialog --title \"Interface\" --menu \"Please choose an option:\" 15 50 5 $args 3 \"Exit\""
```

rather than

```
eval "dialog --title \"Interface\" --menu \"Please choose an option:\" $args 3 \"Exit\""
```